# Laptop will not properly go to sleep or wake up from sleep mode

Tags: laptop, display, sleep, toshiba-laptop, wake-up

I have a Toshiba A505 laptop with Windows 7 SP1 and Nvidia Geforce 310M with driver version `266.58`.

The issue I am having is that the laptop doesn't always properly go to sleep or properly wake from sleep. Sometimes when it goes to sleep, the display turns off but the laptop never goes into sleep mode. Other times when I wake it from sleep, the computer starts up but the display does not turn back on. This is an intermittent problem that I have been having since I purchased the laptop. I have updated everything over Windows Update and have even updated the display drivers to the latest version. Other than formatting and reinstalling Windows, is there anything else I can do?

It is really annoying to have to do hard reboots so often and it can't be good for the computer.

Comment: For me under windows 10 (upgraded from win 7) it was below `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Power Options\Edit Plan Settings` and then click `change advanced power settings` then pick sleep > allow wake timers  and disable them this helped me: https://www.ghacks.net/2013/12/31/find-pc-wakes-stop/

Answer (score 0):

Try to enter to power plans and customize your settings,your computer may go to hibernate so make sure about this point.